# How to pass character with single quotes into a SQL query?

Tags: r

I have developed a R code to pass a file name to a SQL query. But, I need to include single quote to the file name and pass it to the query.

This query below works fine.

```
fn_query("select * from MP.UFUND where LOAD_FILE = 'ps2019_03282019.txt'")
```

But, I have to pass the file name from `file_to_read$file_name` with single quotes to the above query.

So, far I was unsuccessful. I tried with `sQuote` but no success. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `paste0("select ... = '", file_name, "' ...txt")`

Comment: `sql_string <- paste0("select * from MP.UFUND where LOAD_FILE = '", file_to_read$file_name, "'")`.